# Headers in !ACESAPI:acesHttpOperation - Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm using OnProgress callback in my worktitem but I have the following difficulty when I trying to send headers with **!ACESAPI:acesHttpOperation**.

- According to https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/cannot-match-arguments-error-when-using-aceshttpoperation the following line satisfy the regular expression.

```
[08/12/2021 22:59:57] !ACESAPI:acesHttpOperation(GetFormaletas,?pk=30204db6-fe6c-4368-99a0-972781eb66c9,Authorization:Api-Key UI3rAhEG.rP5qlYHuwmw9664udwB9cbKs2OXMpMhX,,file://30204db6-fe6c-4368-99a0-972781eb66c9formaletas.csv)
```

And below you can see what receive each argument.

```
[08/12/2021 22:59:57] !!!!This is an API callback => "!ACESAPI:acesHttpOperation(GetFormaletas,?pk=30204db6-fe6c-4368-99a0-972781eb66c9,Authorization:Api-Key UI3rAhEG.rP5qlYHuwmw9664udwB9cbKs2OXMpMhX,,file://30204db6-fe6c-4368-99a0-972781eb66c9formaletas.csv)"
[08/12/2021 22:59:57] Start processing API request acesHttpOperation.
[08/12/2021 22:59:57] Arguments => name="GetFormaletas", suffix="?pk=30204db6-fe6c-4368-99a0-972781eb66c9", headers="Authorization:Api-Key UI3rAhEG.rP5qlYHuwmw9664udwB9cbKs2OXMpMhX", requestContent="", responseFile="file://30204db6-fe6c-4368-99a0-972781eb66c9formaletas.csv"
[08/12/2021 22:59:57] - Download variadic item from "http://e320ece2e3e5.ngrok.io/projects/get-formaletas-csv?pk=30204db6-fe6c-4368-99a0-972781eb66c9" to "T:\Aces\Jobs\8b53409106af4388855f42e3c4e80f1c\30204db6-fe6c-4368-99a0-972781eb66c9formaletas.csv".
```

But I'm getting a 403 for the lack of the authorization header.

```
[08/12/2021 22:59:57] Error: API failed. Reason = Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.
[08/12/2021 22:59:57] Error: Response = StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
```

In the server it's also visible the lack of the header when I print the request headers

```
Received headers ==> {'Host': 'e320ece2e3e5.ngrok.io', 'X-Forwarded-For': '3.212.238.83', 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'http', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'}
Forbidden: /projects/get-formaletas-csv
HTTP GET /projects/get-formaletas-csv?pk=30204db6-fe6c-4368-99a0-972781eb66c9 403 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:54139]
```

In the documentation I don't see examples with headers, any guidance is welcome. I would also like to know how to send more than one header.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **Design Automation API for Inventor**, the **VS template** project for that actually contains a helper function for that so you can call it like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("MyHeader-Item1", "MyHeader Value1");
dict.Add("MyHeader-Item2", "MyHeader Value2");
Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Inventor.Utils.OnDemand.HttpOperation("OnDemandParam", "", dict, "file://myfile");
```

I checked in the work item report what is generated and it's here:

```
!ACESAPI:acesHttpOperation(OnDemandParam,,MyHeader-Item1=MyHeader Value1;MyHeader-Item2=MyHeader Value2,,file://myfile)
```

Also, checked on [webhook.site](https://webhook.site/) to make sure it works fine - and it does:
[image]

Also updated https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/communicate-servers-inside-design-automation to include that as a sample.

Comment: I am using Design Automation API for revit, but with your recommendations I already got it to work, thank you very much.